# Office Addin reads files from LocalCache instead of Roaming folder on one Windows 10 computer

Tags: c#, office-addins

I have a .Net Office plugin (standard Win32 application) which has worked for several years on different version of Office and OS-es. It's a Word and PowerPoint plugin.

Now I have one customer on latest Windows 10 Pro (Version 1803 build 17134.228) complaining about missing settings, which is written by a different program to the user's Roaming folder. The Office plugin gets the path to the configuration file like this:

```
string localPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), BaseFolder);
```

We found out that the plugin read this file from

```
AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Roaming\
```

instead of the AppData\Roaming folder.

I created a VM with the exact same Windows 10 Pro version and build number, using Office 365, but I could not reproduce the issue.

I [found two others](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_win10-mso_2016/office-saving-fils-to-localcache-instead-of/5a5f768e-25a2-43e7-8315-3c6942231109) who have seen the same issue without any solution.

On [this page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9f30534-8d91-4bdf-8864-3a64f4b71e04/deleting-data-from-appdatalocalpackages?forum=w8itproperf) I read the following

> The files in the C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Packages folder store the user configuration settings for all of the installed Modern UI Apps.
>   These apps use a completely different programming model than the traditional Desktop (Win32) apps.

My app is not a Modern UI App, so I don't understand why this one customer have this issue with the app. Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: I'm having the same issues on one of my customer's computers. On all other computers – the Excel add-in default settings file is stored under C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\Plugin_Name_Path_bso..

On this computer I found the settings file under C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\Addin_Name_Path_bso..
As the result, when the computer is restarted – all settings get lost (I'm guessing because they are inside of a LocalCache folder that gets cleared).

Has anyone found why?

Comment: @taralex No, haven't found out why.

Comment: So the customer's IT reported back and said that this is happening for the Office that came pre-installed from Microsoft. Somehow for preinstalled apps – the settings are stored there. Uninstalling and reinstalling Office normally solved the problem.